# If God only forgives our sins at the Sacrament of Penance, why do ask forgivness in prayer?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, sacraments, confession

In Catholicism and Orthodoxy, forgiveness of sins is only attained at the Sacrament of Penance. What then is the role to pray that God would forgive us our sins? Why pray Our Father, or ask of this at the liturgy?

Comment: But God **does not** forgive our sins **only in the sacrament of penance**!

Comment: The Catholic Church teaches that God also forgives sins in various situations other than the sacrament of penance. The most important of these situations is when the sinner genuinely repents of the sin out of love for God (as opposed to repenting out of fear of hell, fear of the police, shame, etc.).

Comment: @KenGraham True, but [perfect contrition is incompatible with a lack of desire for sacramental (auricular) confession to a priest](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60652/1787).