# Why do Catholics have to go to regular confession to have their sins forgiven if they pray The Lord's Prayer and ask for forgiveness daily?

Tags: catholicism, confession, lords-prayer

This question is more for Catholics I suppose. The Lord's Prayer is a prayer that should be prayed daily i.e. "Give us this day our daily bread".
Why do Catholics have to go to regular confession to have their sins forgiven if they pray The Lord's Prayer and ask for forgiveness daily i.e. "Forgive us our trespasses as we forgive those etc?

Comment: Here you can find the answer: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60647/can-a-person-be-forgiven-outside-of-confession-catholic

Comment: In short, because, [as the Council of Trent declared, perfect contrition includes the desire for sacramental confession](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60652/1787). As @Grasper mentioned, your question is a possible duplicate of [Can a person be forgiven outside of confession? (Catholic)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60647/can-a-person-be-forgiven-outside-of-confession-catholic).

Comment: Our Lord taught his apostles the Lord's Prayer long before the council of Trent. What was the point of adding the petition "forgive us our trespasses as we forgive those etc" if according to your reply this in itself is not adequate? Is it adequate or not?

Answer (score 1):

The Church teaches by Canon Law that a penitent must go to confession for mortal sins (see 1 Jn 5:16-17).  I have also included the prior canon providing an explanation of the proper disposition and intention of the pentitent.

> Canon 959 In the sacrament of penance the faithful who confess their
>   sins to a lawful minister, are sorry for those sins and have a purpose
>   of amendment, receive from God, through the absolution given by that
>   minister, forgiveness of sins they have committed after baptism, and
>   at the same time they are reconciled with the Church, which by sinning
>   they wounded.
>
> Canon 960 Individual and integral confession and absolution constitute
>   the sole ordinary means by which a member of the faithful who is
>   conscious of grave sin is reconciled with God and with the Church.
>   Physical or moral impossibility alone excuses from such confession, in
>   which case reconciliation may be attained by other means also.